# JUnit & Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

can you guys give me a quick, straight to the point explanation of JUnit and Mockito unit testing? I've been searching and it's not have been clear to me.

Also, what kind of unit tests can i make for a Rest server and client?

Here is my rest server code for example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

@Path("/calculator")
public class RESTServer {

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RESTServer.class);

private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

/**
 * Function that converts a String parameter into a Request object
 * @param json is the String of the request received from the client
 * @return return an Request object with all the fields containning data from the json String
 * @throws IOException
 */

private Request convertToObj(final String json) throws IOException {

    final Request request;
    log.debug("Processing request: {}", json);

    request = mapper.readValue(json, Request.class);

    return request;
}

/**
 * Function that converts a Answer object into a JSON String where all the data is written in conformity with JSON conventions
 * @param answerObject is the object with all the data about the answer to retrieve to the client
 * @param json is the String that contains the request, only for logging purposes
 * @return return a JSON String with all the data contained in the object
 * @throws JsonProcessingException
 */

private String convertToJson(final Answer answerObject, final String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String answer;

    answer = mapper.writeValueAsString(answerObject);

    log.debug("Retrieving answer {} for request: {}", answer, json);

    return answer;
}

/**
 * Function that calculates the result of the operation specified in the request from the client
 * @param request is the Request object that contains all the data from the client request
 * @return return the value resultant from the operation made
 */

public double calculator(final Request request){

    log.debug("Processing number: {} and number: {}  with operation: {}", request.getValue1(), request.getValue2(), request.getOperation());

    Calculate calculate = (value1, value2, operation) -> {

        if (operation.compareToIgnoreCase("add") == 0) return value1 + value2;
        else if (operation.compareToIgnoreCase("mult") == 0) return value1 * value2;
        else if (operation.compareToIgnoreCase("div") == 0) return value1 / value2;
        else if (operation.compareToIgnoreCase("avg") == 0) return (value1 + value2)/2;
        else return 0;
    };

    return calculate.obtainResult(request.getValue1(),request.getValue2(),request.getOperation());
}

private interface Calculate{
    double obtainResult(double value1, double value2, String operation);
}

/**
 *Function that builds the answer to send to the client, merge the result of the calculation of the operation, the date and hour of the operation and the operation made
 * @param operation is the operation made
 * @param result is the result of the operation
 * @return returns a Answer object that contains all the data referent to the treatment of the request from the client
 */

private static Answer buildAnswer(final String operation, final double result){

    String date;
    Answer answerObject;

    date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

    answerObject = new Answer(operation, result, date);

    return answerObject;
}

@POST
@Path("/calc")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postRequest(final String json) throws IOException {

    final double result;
    final String answer;
    final Request request;
    final Answer answerObject;

    request = convertToObj(json);

    result = calculator(request);

    answerObject = buildAnswer(request.getOperation(),result);

    answer = convertToJson(answerObject, json);

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(answer).build();
}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: This is much too broad. You need to read the documentation. Also, you need to read the documentation of JAX-RS: your methods shouldn't take Strings as arguments, but objects. JAX-RS will transform the JSON into objects for you.

Comment: thanks , i've been told about that but i  do that the server stops working

Comment: Then you need to read the error and the documentation to understand why.

Comment: it dont leave's any error, it just dont do nothing and dont throw any error